# Parallel for each using double threads expected in TPL

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, task-parallel-library, threadpool, parallel.foreach

I will start this off with a basic explanation of how I understand a couple things to work and then conclude this all with a tldr; if people simply wish to reach the actual question I'm having here.  And please, correct me if my understanding of anything here is wrong.

TPL stands for the Task Parallel Library, which is .NET 4.0's answer to trying to further simplify threading for ease of developer use.  If you're unfamiliar with it, (on a very base level) you start a new Task object and pass it a delegate which is then run on a background thread taken from a thread pool (by using the thread pool instead of truly making a new thread, time and resources are saved by using these existing threads instead of creating and disposing of new threads).

From what I understand, the Parallel.ForEach command in C# will spawn a new thread (likely from a thread pool) for each delegate it is supposed to do, with the possible exception of automatically doing an inline of one or even possibly more of the iterations if the compiler decides they will occur quick enough for that to be more efficient.

Most relevant background information as to my goal:

I am attempting to make a quick program that starts off a Task to run concurrently with the rest of the program.  In this Task, a Parallel.ForEach is run for 3 'iterations.'  In total, we expect the program to now be running 5 total threads (at most): 1 for the main thread, 1 for the actual Task, and up to 3 for the Parallel.ForEach.  Each Thread has its own goals to accomplish (although the Parallel.ForEach all have the same goal with a different value to its related itemNumber to calculate on.  When the main thread finishes all its goals, it uses a Task.Wait() to wait on the finishing task, which waits on the Parallel.ForEach to finish as well.  Then the values are used and verified.

tldr; Actual question:

When the aforementioned idea is run, the Parallel.ForEach appears to be initializing twice as many SynchronizationContexts (a TPL object which is essentially an other thread) as I would expect and running all of them, however only waiting on the expected amount of them.  Because the Parallel.ForEach().Wait() command finishes at the expected quantity of threads running, the Task then also finishes as it thinks everything is done.  Then the main program picks up that the Task has finished and as it verifies that there are currently no more background threads running, occasionally the remaining Parrallel.ForEach() have yet to finish and therefore errors are thrown.

The quantity of threads has been verified to match what I stated by printing to the debug window upon each SynchronizationContext's post call (the Async method kicker).  Each thread is also referenced by a main thread object that otherwise plans on being disposed of upon finishing the Task, but since references are still had due to unfinished threads that weren't truly expected to be created, the disposal can't occur properly.

```
Thread testThread = Thread.CurrentThread;
Task backgroundTask = taskFactory.StartNew(() =>
{
    Thread rootTaskThread = Thread.CurrentThread;
    Assert.AreNotEqual(testThread, rootTaskThread, "First task should not inline");
    Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));

    Parallel.ForEach(new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 },
       new ParallelOptions { TaskScheduler = taskFactory.Scheduler }, (int item) => {
        Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
     });
});
```

In the above example, the main thread, the backgroundTask Task, and 8 Parallel.ForEach threads end up existing, the last 9 of which are created on SynchronizationContexts.

The only method overridden in the SynchronizationContext for my custom is post and is as follows:

```
public override void Post(SendOrPostCallback d, object state){
    Request requestOrNull = Request.ExistsForCurrentThread() ? Request.GetForCurrentThread() as Request : null;
    Request.IAsyncContextData requestData = null;

    if (requestOrNull != null){
       requestData = requestOrNull.CaptureDataForNewThreadAndIncrementReferenceCount();
    }

    Debug.WriteLine("Task started - request data " + (requestData == null ? "DOES NOT EXIST" : "EXISTS"));

    base.Post((object internalState) => {
        // Capture the spawned thread state and restore the originating thread state
        try{
            if (requestData != null){
                Request.AttachToAsynchronousContext(requestData);
            }
            d(state);
        }
        finally{
            // Restore original spawned thread state
            if (requestData != null){
            // Disposes the request if this is the last reference to it
                Request.DetachFromAsynchronousContext(requestData);
            }
        Debug.WriteLine("Task completed - request data " + (requestData == null ? "DOES NOT EXIST" : "EXISTS"));
        }
    }, state);
 }
```

TaskScheduler that I believe is doing only the basic stuff required of it:

```
private readonly RequestSynchronizationContext context;
private readonly ConcurrentQueue<Task> tasks = new ConcurrentQueue<Task>();

public RequestTaskScheduler(RequestSynchronizationContext synchronizationContext)
{
    this.context = synchronizationContext;
}

protected override void QueueTask(Task task){
    this.tasks.Enqueue(task);
    this.context.Post((object state) => {
        Task nextTask;
        if (this.tasks.TryDequeue(out nextTask)) 
            this.TryExecuteTask(nextTask);
    }, null);
}

protected override bool TryExecuteTaskInline(Task task, bool taskWasPreviouslyQueued){
    if (SynchronizationContext.Current == this.context)
        return this.TryExecuteTask(task);
    else
        return false;
}

protected override IEnumerable<Task> GetScheduledTasks(){
    return this.tasks.ToArray();
}
```

TaskFactory:

```
public RequestTaskFactory(RequestTaskScheduler taskScheduler)
    : base(taskScheduler)
{ }
```

Any ideas on why this may be occurring?

Comment: Could you post a short but complete sample which shows your behavior? Especially your `SynchronizationContext` (I assume you're using a custom one). Because I don't see the behavior you're describing. Also, I really don't understand why using `Post()` more than you expected would cause any problems for you? Does your `SynchronizationContext` have some special behavior that depends on this?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by doing this?  The `Assert.AreNotEqual` suggests to me you're writing some sort of unit test.  But, the `Assert.AreNotEqual` is really validating the TPL, not your code--so, I don't see the point of verifying third-party code.

Answer (score 0):

Task itself doesn't create threads.  It's up to the TaskScheduler to decide what to do in order to make the operations asynchronous, if they can be.  e.g. Some operations use asynchronous IO, in which case the hardware makes it asynchronous, not another worker thread.

How continuations are invoked depends on the synchronization context.  that context *is not another thread*, it just abstracts the criteria by which actions can be run.  In WPF, WinForms, Silverlight, etc, for example there is a UI synchronization context for which actions need to be executed on a **specific thread** (the UI thread, or the main thread, to avoid exceptions).

ForEach will *try* to create threads (more specifically it will try the ask the synchronization context to start multiple asynchronous operations).  The scheduler defines really how it does that.  If you give it three tasks, *it may* create three threads or *it may not*.  It decides on whether three concurrent threads would be a good thing or not.  If you only have two cores, for example, ForEach won't create more than two threads because that would likely be worse that using a single thread and running the code sequentially due to context switching overhead.

It's not clear what you mean by "initializing twice as many SynchronizationContext".  These are not threads.  Do you simply mean it's creating more threads than you expected?  Or do you mean Post was called more than you expected?  What is your SynchronizationContext class based on? (i.e. what is it's base class).  What the base does largely defines how may Post invocations there will be.  It may feel the need to create another asynchronous operation to keep track of the other operations...  How are you getting the scheduler to use this context?

SynchronizationContext existed well before TPL (appeared first in .NET 2.0).  One of the things it does is manage asynchronous operation requests.  It's not clear from you post whether or not you understand that.

**Update:**
The first call to QueueTask comes indirectly from the StartNew.
The second call to QueueTask comes indirectly from the call to ForEach
the third call to QueueTask comes indirectly from the TryExecuteTask in QueueTask
The next 4 calls to QueueTask are for the body passed to ForEach.

Depending on load, QueueTask may be called up to 3 more times.  If I debug and break at QueueTask, QueueTask is only called 7 times.

At this point, since you're doing something different than the TPL in your QueueTask (i.e. TryExecuteTask is invoking an extra operation) it's hard to say why there is sometimes some extra QueueTask calls.  It could be from the way you've implemented QueueTask as you're effectively asking the scheduler to queue another asynchronous task from the task that's already executing asynchronously.  My guess is that it's simply timing.  QueueTask can be invoked so quickly (since that's done from another asynchronous operation) that TryExecuteTask doesn't know the task is already queued and forces the task to execute (forcing *another* call to QueueTask).

If QueueTask is in fact causing another call to QueueTask because it hasn't already scheduled the tasks it's in, that explains why there are up to 10 calls to QueueTask.  It's the TryExeucteTask call that's causing the "double" invocation per ForEach body...

Comment: My SynchronizationContext directly extends the base SynchronizationContext and no other methods besides post are overridden.
And yes, post is called more than I expected.  For each iteration in the ForEach loop, 2 post calls are made.  Or at the very least, it comes in such that a ForEach of size 3 results in 7 total post calls, size 4 results in 9 post calls, etc...  
The base TaskScheduler is also used as well as a base TaskFactory with no overridden methods in either.
And you are correct, I was not aware SynchronizationContext existed prior to TPL.

Comment: TaskScheduler is an abstract class; how are you implementing those abstract methods?  Also, how are you implementing TaskFactory?  You're doing something different than the TPL.  How are you setting your TaskFactory's Scheduler property? I don't know if you're using the default task scheduler (which is either SynchronizationContextTaskScheduler or ThreadPoolTaskScheduler) so, it appears like you're comparing apples and oranges.

Comment: Added my implemention of the TaskScheduler, TaskFactory is as simple as I added as well.  As for any TaskFactory Scheduler property, that would be something I'm unaware of ever having had to do?

Comment: @KevinMoore I've added detail to my answer, but I believe it's because the call to `TryExecuteTask` in `QueueTask` is too fast and forcing the existing task (which is already running asynchronously) to run the task asynchronously.

Comment: Thank you this helps a lot!  But when you say that depending on load, the QueueTask may be called up to 3 more times - how exactly would that end up happening?  I mean what exactly will end up calling it those extra times (likely indirectly then I assume?).

Comment: The details are implementation details of the TPL; but, I noticed that when you call `TryExecuteTask` that may up calling `QueueTask`.  Of course, `TryExecuteTask` is called *from* `QueueTask` via the call to `RequestSynchronizationContext.Post`.  The TPL isn't written this way, so I assume wouldn't have these results.